# Perl die with string without appending file name and line number

Tags: perl

Is there a way of `die`ing in Perl in such a way that `$@` is not modified? As far as I can tell, `die` mangles the contents of `$@` under certain circumstances and "throws", transferring control non-locally. I just want to do the latter.

When `die` is a string appends the file name and line number to `$@` when the exceptionish object passed to `die` is a string (or undef).

For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# foo.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

eval { die '1'; };
my $hash_ref = {
    msg => $@,
};

print Dumper($hash_ref);
```

prints:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'msg' => '1 at foo.pl line 7.
'
        };
```

But if the argument is not a string (or undef) it isn't modified.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# foo2.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

eval { die ['string-inside-arrayref']; };
my $hash_ref = {
    msg => $@,
};

print Dumper($hash_ref);
```

This snippet produces:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'msg' => [
                     'string-inside-arrayref'
                   ]
        };
```

Comment: Are you issuing a `die` yourself?  To suppress line/file info add a newline, `die "$string\n";`. Otherwise you can set a hook for it, `$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { ...}`, and format it inside as you please. See [%SIG in perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%SIG)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`perldoc -f die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html):

> **die LIST**
>
> `die` raises an exception. [...]
>
> If the last element of LIST does not end in a newline, the current script line number and input line number (if any) are also printed, and a newline is supplied.

If you want to suppress the addition of file name and line number, make sure your error message ends with `"\n"`.

To rethrow an existing exception, you can simply use `die $@`. Either `$@` is an exception object (then it won't get mangled anyway), or it is a string ending with `"\n"` (because the previous `die` will have made sure to add one if there wasn't one to begin with).

Comment: That seems fine for user code, but I'm trying to write a library that catches, inspects, and possibly rethrows exceptions. I'd like to be able to rethrow exactly the exception I was handed, even if the exception object has been set to a non-newline delimited string in an XS module or something like that.